# Moving rows between MySQL tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables with the same structure, and both contain an ID field of `auto_increment`.
I would like to move a row from one table to the other.

I know I can use:

```
INSERT INTO `new_table` VALUES (SELECT * FROM `old_table`)
```

But that way the ID in `new_table` will receive the ID of `old_table`. So I would basically want to copy all fields except for the ID, which needs to get the `auto_increment` value of `new_table`. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Joel

---

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I should have mentioned in my original post - I would like a way to do it without selecting each field specifically, mostly since I have a lot of fields... I am looking for a more generic approach.

Thanks!

Comment: wow! 4 exact same responses in a minute! be happy. :)

Comment: hehe, it was my bad, I should have mentioned I am looking for a generic approach in my original post... I edited it now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
INSERT INTO `new_table` (name, surname, email) 
  (SELECT name, email, surname FROM `old_table`);
```

Be careful though when letting the MySQL automatically assign new IDs in case there are relations from other tables you need to move as well.

In such cases I'll move the whole data around by adding a known offset to the ID which will be large enough to avoid ID collisions in the target table. Since the offset is known I'll be able to apply the same offset when moving relations (to the target table) from other tables.

**Edit based on question edit**: I highly suggest to avoid "the generic approach". It may seem pedantic having to write all the fields but it's the only way to avoid mistakes and, of course, the ID collision problem. If you want to avoid typing the fieldnames (since it's boring and error prone) you can copy paste the fieldnames from `show create table new_table`.

Comment: Thanks, probably better doing it your way!

Answer (score 1):

Do not select id in that case:

```
INSERT INTO `new_table` (`field2`, `field3`) VALUES (SELECT `field2`, `field3` FROM `old_table`)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO `new_table` (COLS-I-WANT) 
VALUES (SELECT (OLD-COLS-I-WANT) FROM `old_table`)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Speciy the column names in both INSERT list and SELECT list excluding the ID column